# ImageJ Macro: Undefined Variable when saving an image to a directory

Tags: imagej, fiji

When I am changing open image window it forgets the directory, how can I retrieve it to save again
This is how I create a direcotry in Stack image folder

```
dir=getDirectory("image");
print(dir)
splitDir= dir + "OneChannel";
File.makeDirectory(splitDir);
print(splitDir);
```

This is where I change the active image window to Montage.tiff to save it to splitDir folder

```
title= getTitle()
saveAs("tiff",splitDir+title);
```

The error is undefined variable. Should I make global splitdir to keep it when I change the active image window

```
Error:      Undefined variable in line 2:
        saveAs ( "tiff" , <splitDir> + title ) ;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Variables in ImageJ macros are case-sensitive. In your code you have defined `splitDir` but have not defined `splitdir`, hence the error.
Change the line to `saveAs("tiff",splitDir+title);` and it should work.

Comment: Hi, good point, that was a mistake and I have corrected it. My point is, when I am running macro script lines separately somehow it does not remember the directory of my preferences and throws null. I guess there is no variable storing like in Matlab workspace